# setting array parameter in hibernate Query object

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

This is how my plpqsql functions (Postgres function) looks like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(my_ids text[]) RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '--- Processing data%', my_ids;
END;
$function$;
```

and executing the above function like this

```
SELECT test('{"This", "is", "very", "cool"}'::TEXT[]);
```

till here my code works fine but when i am trying to call this select query from my application's code i have no idea how do i set it in the query.
below is my java code

```
String query = "SELECT public.test( ? );";
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query);

List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
strList.add("hello");
strList.add("world");
String[] strParam = strList.toArray(new String[strList.size()]);
sqlQuery.setParameter(1, strParam);  // this is not working what shall i use for it ?
sqlQuery.executeUpdate();
```

so my question as mentioned in the code comment is how do i set this array in the query.

I can use it in JDBC like this

```
Array strParam= conn.createArrayOf("varchar", strList.toArray(new String[strList.size()]));
```

and then setting this sqlArray in preparedStatement using setArray method !

but any idea how should i do it with hibernate ?

Thanks in anticipation !

Comment: Have you tried the method setParameterList  of Hibernate query?